# Trying to understand the logic and "crutches" of errorlevel

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt, logical-operators

I have it here .bat file and I'm trying to figure something out. My brain is just boiling from trying to realize what is wrong here!

Here is my code:

```
echo off
setlocal
cls

:perm_ask
echo Make a permanent format? 
CHOICE /C YN /N /T 15 /D N /M "Press Y for Yes and N for No: "
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 set perm=TRUE
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 set perm=FALSE

goto select_format

:select_format
cls
if "%perm%"=="TRUE" (echo You have selected the permanent save mode. Be CAREFUL! & echo.):: checking for truth

echo Select the file format:
echo =============
echo 1) .fb2 format
echo 2) .epub format
echo 3) .fb2 + .epub formats

CHOICE /C 123 /N /M "Format: "

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 set form=fb2
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 set form=epub
IF ERRORLEVEL 3 set form=fb2,epub

goto url_insert

:url_insert
cls
if "%perm%"=="TRUE" (echo TRUEEEE) else (echo FALSEEE):: checking for truth

if "%form%"=="fb2,epub" (echo You have chosen the .epub and .fb2 format
    ) else (echo You have chosen the .%form% format)
echo. 
set /p url=Insert the URL: 

Elib2Ebook.exe -u %url% -f %form%

if "%perm%"=="TRUE" (goto url_insert) else (goto ask_cont)

:ask_cont
echo. 
set ERRORLEVEL=0:: trying to reset a huge negative value
CHOICE /C YN /M "Continue? "
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto select_format
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 goto exit

:exit
@exit
```

In `perm_ask` I ask whether to set a permanent file format.

In `select_form` I assign values to `form`

In `url_insert` I insert the link and the execution of the program is done

In `ask_count`, if I answered no in `perm_ask`, it is asked to continue or exit...

After all, if I don't change the order, even if I'm in `Continue?` the answer is No, it still goes to `select_form`

And so the question is. If I had everything in order with ERRORLEVEL before, I didn't even need to arrange it in reverse order (BECAUSE IT DOESN'T WORK FOR SOME REASON!). Then in `url_insert` I have a problem with `Continue?` if not to change the order or not to do so:

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == "1" goto select_format
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == "2" goto exit
```

So here's the question... why? Why is everything fine before that, but then you either need to change the order, or assign ERRORLEVEL to a variable? I tried changing the order for ERRORLEVEL in other places (`perm_ask` and `select_form`), but it only broke everything!

Comment: `if ErrorLevel 1` means *if ErrorLevel is **equal to or greater than** 1*. To fix your code, simple reorder your `if ErrorLevel` from the greatest to the least value…

Comment: Never do `set ERRORLEVEL=xyz`...

Comment: Please do not replace your question content, with a simple thank you. It remains in place for future readers, and/or for further answers. I have returned it to its condition prior to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got multiple things going on here.

The syntax `if errorlevel 1` means "if `%errorlevel%` is 1 *or higher*" so `if errorlevel 1` will always be triggered by choice if it is the first thing. This is the reason that they should be arranged in descending order.

Additionally, `if` statements include quotes in the comparison, so *both* `IF %ERRORLEVEL% == "1"` and `IF %ERRORLEVEL% == "2"` return false, since `1` is not equal to `"1"`. If you want to use an `if` statement, put quotes around both things:

```
IF "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "1" goto select_format
IF "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "2" goto exit
```

Comment: It's just that if you change the order of "ERRORLEVEL" to `perm_ask`, then it incorrectly determines the answer. Why? After all, if I change the order and choose the second option, that is, it should make the variable `perm` = FALSE, but the determinant in `select_format` claims that I chose the first option, and there it doesn't matter which one I choose, it will constantly write that the value is true, as if I choose `IF ERRORLEVEL 1 set perm=TRUE`, even if it is the second

Comment: Because selecting `N` for your choice command sets the value of `%errorlevel%` to 2, and since `if errorlevel 1` and `if errorlevel 2` are _both_ true in that scenario, both `if` statements are executed.

Comment: Then why aren't all the conditions met in `select_format`? And the second question is, why does `perm_ask` and `select_format` break down if you change the order, the brain still hurts a little

Comment: For the same reason. In `:select_format`, let's say you pick `2` and the errorlevels are listed 1, 2, 3. `if errorlevel 1` is true, so `form` gets set to `fb2`. `if errorlevel 2` is also true, so the value of `form` gets overwritten as `epub`. `if errorlevel 3` is not true, so the value of `form` does not change.

Comment: If you remove the `echo off` from the top of your script, it'll be easier to see what's going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

Originally, there was one syntax for `if errorlevel` which was

```
if errorlevel n dosomething
```

which was, and is interpreted as `if errorlevel is n OR GREATER THAN n`.

Consequently, testing needed to be done in reverse order of errorlevel and spaghetti-code was generated to have the various expected errorlevels do multiple things.

Later, `errorlevel` was introduced as a magic variable, set by the system, and `else` was made available to complement `if`.

Backward compatility dictates that the old functionality needs to be maintained to avoid having to re-write existing programs.

So - you choose to use `%errorlevel%` or the original syntax as suits your situation.